# approximate search in a database

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql, fuzzy-search

I have a large database with a list of institutions (universities, hospitals, etc). The names of institutions come from different sources and can be spelled differently for the same institution. They can be misspelled, for example, or words can be shortened ("uni", or "univ", or "university")

Given a name that I need to insert in to the database, is there a practical way to find if this institution is already in the database? This is not a research project, so I am looking for a solution that is reasonably fast.

I am using django and postgresql, but it does not matter I suppose.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you running?

Comment: I can install any version. So, the latest I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem of [record linkage](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Record_linkage). Many databases provide basic methods for this such as character-level *n*-gram matching, where a term like "university" is expanded into

["uni", "niv", "ive", "ver", "ers", ...]

for *n* = 3. The database would index all such *n*-grams and allow a search with some kind of weighted matching. [`pg_trgm`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) seems to do exactly this, try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look into using a dedicated search engine. [Django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) enables you to *easily* add search engines like Solr, Whoosh or Xapian to your project.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to find a value in the database with a small lexical distance from the value you're given. Finding things with prefixes is fairly straightforward, but misspelled words are harder. You might want to read [Peter Norvig's post on spell correctors](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

Comment: This would be nice if Norvig's algorithm wouldn't be so extremely naïve. Weighted Levenshtein automata (perhaps in a trie form) would make it work, but would still have to be implemented on the database side to prevent extreme numbers of accesses for every fuzzy search. Good luck with that...